# How to override node_search_execute() to implement partial matching search?

Tags: nodes, search

I would like to override [node_search_execute](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_search_execute/7), so the search query will find partial match of a word instead of full word match i.e *coffee*, I would like partial match *coff* should return *coffee* result.

How can I override `node_search_execute()` to implement partial matching search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hook_search_execute()` is a hook that modules integrating with the Search module implement to execute the search. As such, `hook_search_execute()` is invoked only for those modules that have a tab in the search page, not for every modules implementing it. Since the Search module doesn't use `hook_search_execute_alter()` there isn't a quick method to totally override `node_search_execute()`.

There are some way to make Drupal call another function instead of `node_search_execute()`, but those involve writing code. The quicker is probably altering the *search/node* menu to change the page callback, which normally is
[`search_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21search%21search.pages.inc/function/search_view/7).

```
foreach (search_get_info() as $module => $search_info) {
  $path = 'search/' . $search_info['path'];
  $items[$path] = array(
    'title' => $search_info['title'],
    'page callback' => 'search_view',
    'page arguments' => array($module, ''),
    'access callback' => '_search_menu_access',
    'access arguments' => array($module),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'file' => 'search.pages.inc',
    'weight' => $module == $default_info['module'] ? -10 : 0,
  );
  $items["$path/%menu_tail"] = array(
    'title' => $search_info['title'],
    'load arguments' => array('%map', '%index'),
    'page callback' => 'search_view',
    'page arguments' => array($module, 2),
    'access callback' => '_search_menu_access',
    'access arguments' => array($module),
    // The default local task points to its parent, but this item points to
    // where it should so it should not be changed.
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'file' => 'search.pages.inc',
    'weight' => 0,
    // These tabs are not subtabs.
    'tab_root' => 'search/' . $default_info['path'] . '/%',
    // These tabs need to display at the same level.
    'tab_parent' => 'search/' . $default_info['path'],
  );
}
```

Since the goal you are trying to achieve is allowing searching by partial matching, you just need to install one of the modules that allows this, such as:

- The [Porter-Stemmer](http://drupal.org/project/porterstemmer) module
- The [Fuzzy Search](http://drupal.org/project/fuzzysearch) module
- The *Apache Solr Search Integration* module

The first module is the lighter one, since it doesn't depend from other modules, while the second one requires the *Search API* module, which in turn requires the *Entity API* module; the third one integrates with Apache Solr, and it is just a possibility for you if you have a server running Apache Solr. The [Search API](http://drupal.org/project/search_api) module also integrates with Apache Solr.

#### Reference

- [Drupal 7: Partial word search](http://www.accella.net/drupal-7-partial-word-search/)

Comment: Thanks @kiamlaluno for the answer. But my question is simply how to make the search query using operator like on the keywords. Example query: `select * from site_index where word like %coff%`

Comment: And I answered it.